# Updating the value of an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

In a certain function, I’m assigning the value of an array to another array like so…

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(with…

controller.grpDataArray = groupDetailsArray  <-- HERE
```

Now, after this line `controller.grpDataArray = groupDetailsArray` the control goes to another function where the array `groupDetailsArray` gets populated.

Now what I want to achieve is I want to update the value of `groupDetailsArray` and `controller.grpDataArray` as and when the array value changes. I think this can be done through using getter..setter. But not sure how..or is the approach a different one..?

Comment: I"m not sure what you want to achieve here. Do you want to change the value of `grpDataArray` whenever the value of `groupDetailsArray` changes? or you want to do some calculations when the `groupDetailsArray` is assigned to  `grpDataArray` ?

Comment: yes @JayMayu I want to change the value of `grpDataArray `whenever the value of `groupDetailsArray` changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is when when executing this line `controller.grpDataArray = groupDetailsArray`. You are essentially deep copying it. Which mean it will copy everything from structure to values and create a clone and then treat it as a separate variable. Which means even if you update one variable other will not get affected. There are couple of ways to go about achieving what you want to achieve.

1) Create grpDataArray as a singleton and update it accordingly.

2) Use KVO.

3) Use Notifications or delegates.

4) I am not aware of how you shallow copy an array in Swift but if there is go for that instead of this.

Here's an example of singleton.

Create a swift file called Singleton.swift as a subclass of NSObject. in that do as following:

```
class Singleton: NSObject {
    static let shared = Singleton()
    var grpArray: Array<Any>!
}
```

Now in any of the View Controllers.

To initialize

```
Singleton.shared.grpArray = Array()
```

To Update

```
Singleton.shared.grpArray.append(10)
```

To Log

```
print(Singleton.shared.grpArray)
```

P.S The singletons do not persist, meaning as soon as the application is killed. grpArray will lose all the data it holds.

Comment: ok @iOSer...would u maybe mind explaining one of the methods..?

Comment: Explaining as in? Do you want me to write the code for you?

Comment: sure lemme know if you face any issues!

Comment: sure @iOSer.. Thanks..:)

Comment: @v.bw did it this answer serve your purpose?

Comment: very sorry for the late response @iOSer..your answer was useful...Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var groupDetailsArray: [String]? {
    didSet{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier here") as? controllerHere

        controller?.grpDataArray = groupDetailsArray
    }
}
```

Comment: ok @Shezad and where should I add this code..?In a new class..?

Comment: no instead of initializing groupDetailsArray =  [String]()  , use the above code to initialize

Comment: @Shezad your answer is valid, but costly.. Better to assign controller?.grpDataArray = groupDetailsArray when second time when the array value changes as u mentioned in ques

Comment: Sure @Shezad..:)

Comment: @ViJayAvhad can you please explain what you mean by costly??

Comment: @ViJayAvhad..In this case the value of `groupDetailsArray` changes multiple times..it is not just 2 times..So if I assign the value as ` controller?.grpDataArray = groupDetailsArray ` whenever the array value changes, the array will have duplicate records..

Comment: well... though u are updating value of parent array multiple times, does it need to update real time to chield array ?? And creating new references of ViewController is for sure, each time to assign the value is costly..

Comment: @ViJayAvhad how is it creating new references? it just execute the code inside didSet everytime you changes the value of  groupDetailsArray, its just same like the working of a variable declaration

Comment: ok.. the point is, why he is updating value each time, he can do only finally he wants to present second vc..

Comment: @ViJayAvhad that depends on him.